# Why are mongoDB counts incorrect?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My data looks like this:

```
 {
       "_id":ObjectId("516fbf68067323ce2ea5b4b8"),
       "title":"GVPKFlFIXdLUaLM",
       "release_year":1913,
       "country_of_origin":"sWdXLXUfun",
       "length_in_minutes":147,
       "plot_summary":"bmwYkyyiSymHJYoXEPauPNjdKoFANDgcDImVelDGPuPJmLhyWOuNXjurNyGp",
       "director":"rNDFhhxGIo",
       "language":"oYeWskT",
       "popularity":5.2,
       "genre":"jDwdaMhuT",
       "actors":[
          {
             "id":2740,
             "name":"actor2740",
             "dob":1989,
             "alt_name":"PBpXPqJwmftpfcR",
             "pob":"DFoxETDuhAdDGNE"
          },
          {
             "id":3143,
             "name":"actor3143",
             "dob":1953,
             "alt_name":"AHnVvTviSKuvNZO",
             "pob":"KBUdvbnvNkXmddk"
          }
       ]
    }
```

At first I thought there was a bug in Mongo. I attempted to solve a hypothetical business problem using the aggregate function. (edit: I didn't mean to say that I resolved a mongo issue or that I want people to help me create an algorithm, only to confirm a potential bug with MongoDB)

```
db.movies.aggregate([{$match:{popularity:{$gte:7.3}}},
     {$project:{actors:1,popularity:1}},
     {$unwind:"$actors"},
     {$group:{_id:"$actors.id",avgPop:{$avg:"$popularity"},
              docsByTag : { $sum : 1 }, popSum:{$sum:"$popularity"}}},
    {$match:{avgPop:{$gte:7.5}}}]);
```

result I focused on (edit $sum: 1 not 0)

```
{
            "_id" : 1383,
            "avgPop" : 8.772857142857141,
            "docsByTag" : 28,
            "popSum" : 245.63999999999996
        },
```

But when I verified the result by hand.

```
db.movies.find({"actors.name":"actor1383"},{title:1,popularity:1,_id: 0})

{ "title" : "kZFfBwtAfVNobEq", "popularity" : 8.54 }
{ "title" : "kyOeSorYUWyJmjK", "popularity" : 8.11 }
{ "title" : "rvSdJCgEkkpYgFB", "popularity" : 8.36 }
{ "title" : "SwcgHTgZqqcYJja", "popularity" : 8.68 }
{ "title" : "XmcidmdwtDlNoKw", "popularity" : 7.33 }
{ "title" : "gwThvrWifoKCvyG", "popularity" : 7.94 }
{ "title" : "RdUsAFIxTnntTZR", "popularity" : 6.91 }
{ "title" : "RwhJlORFdvtDtpO", "popularity" : 5.13 }
{ "title" : "TuDfcWhNkQFeycl", "popularity" : 9.93 }
{ "title" : "xTVkwnyvftKQraC", "popularity" : 7.27 }
{ "title" : "HYMjUFlSXgnWVTx", "popularity" : 6.94 }
{ "title" : "ZPPyAUdGMeVQhbK", "popularity" : 8.48 }
{ "title" : "kEITAiMMrWTECGM", "popularity" : 9.42 }
{ "title" : "asNsLYKjvHlihXZ", "popularity" : 9.86 }
{ "title" : "ctEmciXPhbMtspt", "popularity" : 8.85 }
{ "title" : "DHjFtctccwDHtlf", "popularity" : 5.5 }
{ "title" : "ElUqbLqkoKrJPVl", "popularity" : 8.26 }
{ "title" : "XdTCieKsWtTbfZa", "popularity" : 5.72 }
{ "title" : "EeNqOPSuKiHuWRs", "popularity" : 5.91 }
{ "title" : "YgysqxcesvPryMY", "popularity" : 6.05 }
{ "title" : "eARvpGydsWilquc", "popularity" : 7.34 }
{ "title" : "NDpdkhSUfePDYjH", "popularity" : 7.28 }
{ "title" : "wUGKLBwijftQKgU", "popularity" : 8.97 }
{ "title" : "UHVGUmAcjBgAPBp", "popularity" : 7.44 }
{ "title" : "NKTKEKfbxFrudVi", "popularity" : 9.4 }
{ "title" : "AeByTKwsEQuQBYG", "popularity" : 8.97 }
{ "title" : "nZskARfGbhYRxdY", "popularity" : 9.16 }
{ "title" : "nBenZrikXFFrrnq", "popularity" : 7.58 }
{ "title" : "GdEFwoKgqjhHvjM", "popularity" : 6.3 }
{ "title" : "grpKTHgnYcDNyXH", "popularity" : 7.16 }
{ "title" : "hXhOqknvjIYJIaT", "popularity" : 5.24 }
{ "title" : "rggTJENnVeuqQVI", "popularity" : 9.95 }
{ "title" : "ABvGVFHkgOumMPO", "popularity" : 9.56 }
{ "title" : "baVkepHniIURUFH", "popularity" : 9.28 }
{ "title" : "PUYXlhPwbanMDmT", "popularity" : 9.6 }
{ "title" : "IJbqonvsVeorDMv", "popularity" : 7.82 }
{ "title" : "iAhyATKYpCVjtMw", "popularity" : 5.88 }
{ "title" : "uDECLFQGTOVnyvC", "popularity" : 6.25 }
{ "title" : "rTwfCYLfLwgPcbH", "popularity" : 8.38 }
{ "title" : "GRyKjecBHQhvYJk", "popularity" : 9.11 }
{ "title" : "GyEaSHoprUvGmZM", "popularity" : 9.92 }
```

which gives a subset of 27 elements greater or equal to 7.3

```
{ "title" : "kZFfBwtAfVNobEq", "popularity" : 8.54 }
{ "title" : "kyOeSorYUWyJmjK", "popularity" : 8.11 }
{ "title" : "rvSdJCgEkkpYgFB", "popularity" : 8.36 }
{ "title" : "SwcgHTgZqqcYJja", "popularity" : 8.68 }
{ "title" : "XmcidmdwtDlNoKw", "popularity" : 7.33 }
{ "title" : "gwThvrWifoKCvyG", "popularity" : 7.94 }
{ "title" : "TuDfcWhNkQFeycl", "popularity" : 9.93 }
{ "title" : "ZPPyAUdGMeVQhbK", "popularity" : 8.48 }
{ "title" : "kEITAiMMrWTECGM", "popularity" : 9.42 }
{ "title" : "asNsLYKjvHlihXZ", "popularity" : 9.86 }
{ "title" : "ctEmciXPhbMtspt", "popularity" : 8.85 }
{ "title" : "ElUqbLqkoKrJPVl", "popularity" : 8.26 }
{ "title" : "eARvpGydsWilquc", "popularity" : 7.34 }
{ "title" : "wUGKLBwijftQKgU", "popularity" : 8.97 }
{ "title" : "UHVGUmAcjBgAPBp", "popularity" : 7.44 }
{ "title" : "NKTKEKfbxFrudVi", "popularity" : 9.4 }
{ "title" : "AeByTKwsEQuQBYG", "popularity" : 8.97 }
{ "title" : "nZskARfGbhYRxdY", "popularity" : 9.16 }
{ "title" : "nBenZrikXFFrrnq", "popularity" : 7.58 }
{ "title" : "rggTJENnVeuqQVI", "popularity" : 9.95 }
{ "title" : "ABvGVFHkgOumMPO", "popularity" : 9.56 }
{ "title" : "baVkepHniIURUFH", "popularity" : 9.28 }
{ "title" : "PUYXlhPwbanMDmT", "popularity" : 9.6 }
{ "title" : "IJbqonvsVeorDMv", "popularity" : 7.82 }
{ "title" : "rTwfCYLfLwgPcbH", "popularity" : 8.38 }
{ "title" : "GRyKjecBHQhvYJk", "popularity" : 9.11 }
{ "title" : "GyEaSHoprUvGmZM", "popularity" : 9.92 }
```

one less than the aggregate function.

So I thought may be aggregate is broken and rewrote this as mapReduce

```
// make sure we're using the right db; this is the same as "use aggdb;" in shell
db = db.getSiblingDB("recommendations"); //Put your MongoLab database name here.



var mapFunc2 = function() {
                       for (var idx = 0; idx < this.actors.length; idx++) {
                           var key = this.actors[idx].id;
                           var value = {
                                         count: 1,
                                         pop: this.popularity
                                       };
                           emit(key, value);
                       }
                    };

var reduceFunc2 = function(keyActor, countObjVals) {


                     reducedVal = { actor: keyActor, count: 0, pop: 0, pop_list : [] };

                     for (var idx = 0; idx < countObjVals.length; idx++) {
                         reducedVal.count += countObjVals[idx].count;
                         reducedVal.pop += countObjVals[idx].pop;
                         reducedVal.pop_list = reducedVal.pop_list.concat(countObjVals[idx].pop);
                     }

                     return reducedVal;
                  };

var finalizeFunc2 = function (key, reducedVal) {

                       reducedVal.avg = reducedVal.pop/reducedVal.count;

                       return reducedVal;

                    };


result = db.movies.mapReduce( mapFunc2,
                     reduceFunc2,
                     {
                       out: { merge: "mre" },
                       query: { popularity:
                                  { $gte: 7.3 }
                              },
                       finalize: finalizeFunc2
                     }
                   )
cursor = db.map_reduce_example.find()                  

while(cursor.hasNext()){
    printjson(cursor.next());
```

}

The result is again off by one

```
{
    "_id" : 1383,
    "value" : {
        "actor" : 1383,
        "count" : 28,
        "pop" : 245.63999999999996,
        "avg" : 8.772857142857141
    }
}
```

So I started debugging and I see some strange things when it comes to saving the popularity of each individual movie in the array.

{ "_id" : 1, "value" : { "actor" : 1, "count" : 13, "pop" : 114.97, "pop_list" : [ 7.47, 8.52, 9.95, 17.4, 7.4, 19.43, 8.46, 17.21, 9.24, 9.89 ], "avg" : 8.843846153846155 } }

Here, it's strange that the count is 13 but the number of elements is 10. This is because of

```
7.4 7.4
7.47    7.47
8.07    1
8.14    2
8.46    8.46
8.52    8.52
9.14    1
9.24    9.24
9.26    2
9.57    3
9.86    3
9.89    9.89
9.95    9.95
```

where 1,2,3 correspond to

```
1   17.21=9.14+8.07
2   17.4=8.14+9.26
3   19.43=9.57+9.86
```

{ "_id" : 2, "value" : { "actor" : 2, "count" : 14, "pop" : 120.91999999999999, "pop_list" : [ 35.239999999999995, 7.58, 35.56, 9.35, 25.839999999999996, 7.35 ], "avg" : 8.637142857142857 } }
However, the above is totally cryptic since all my averages have only 2 decimals place of precision.

Really confused at this point. I'm sure this post could be helpful to others who are stuck figuring the same type of counting problems.

Comment: What are you trying to count?  You start talking about solution without stating your problem.

Comment: Do you have a cut-n-paste error in your aggregation?  You show {$sum:0} and that gives 0.  Are you using the latest version?

Comment: Asya, thank you for catching the {$sum:0} it is def. not what I meant to type. I was showing the aggregate to a friend and accidentally replaced the 1 with a 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's highly unlikely that aggregation framework and mapreduce are both making a "mistake" so I would ask you to verify how you are comparing their results with your expectation.

In your aggregations, you group on `"actors.id"` field.  But your query to verify things manually is:

```
db.movies.find({"actors.name":"actor1383"},{title:1,popularity:1,_id: 0})
```

Is there evidence that your "actors.name" and "actors.id" fields match up 100%?

The precision of higher than 2 digits is normal when you do floating point arithmetic and nothing to worry about.   It's no different than asking for average of 5 and 10 and getting 7.5 even though 5 and 10 both had no digits after the decimal point.

There is another place where the "difference" may come from.   If you have a document like this:

{ popularity: 7.6,
  actors: [
    { id: 1383,
      ...
      ...
    },
    { id: 1383,
      ...
      ...
    }
}

You will now have only one top level document that this contributes to, but when you unwind the actors array you now have TWO document that result from this where both have actor.id 1383.  Can you verify that each actor only appears once per top level document?  If not that would lead to the discrepancy you see.

Comment: Asya, thank you for your answer. Let's focus on aggregate for a second. The agg({$match:{popularity:{$gte:7.3}}}) is supposed excluded all the movie records with pop lower than 7.3
Actor 1383 has 41 movies:
> db.runCommand({count: 'movies', query:{'actors.id':1383,popularity:{$gte:0}}})
{ "n" : 41, "ok" : 1 } see my original post for detailed output
and now
> db.runCommand({count: 'movies', query:{'actors.id':1383,popularity:{$gte:7.3}}})
{ "n" : 27, "ok" : 1 }

How can that be? Both the aggregation and mapReduce give count of 28.
That makes no sense to me.

Comment: Asya, just to reinforce why I think this is a Mongo bug I reran the query 
db.movies.aggregate([{$project:{actors:1,popularity:1}},{$unwind:"$actors"},{$group:{_id:"$actors.id",avgPop:{$avg:"$popularity"},docsByTag : { $sum : 1 }, popSum:{$sum:"$popularity"}}},{$match:{avgPop:{$gte:0}}}]);

And I took the match before the project out completely. But you see the problem is still there. The count should be 41 but is 42. And the popSum look really wrong because due to the precision.
{
   "_id" : 1383,
   "avgPop" : 7.932857142857144,
   "docsByTag" : 42,
   "popSum" : 333.18000000000006
  }

Comment: I changed my answer based on rereading your edited question - I think you are mainly concerned about mismatch of counts when you compare it to manual query but your query is different than aggr field you are using.

Comment: All the data is generated by me using a java loader. In any case here it is again (see my 1st in response)

> db.runCommand({count: 'movies', query:{'actors.id':1383,popularity:{$gte:0}}})
{ "n" : 41, "ok" : 1 }

Not 42!!I just don't know. It really seems like Mongo bug. I can do a dump of my db.
I tried debugging, that is printing all the "pop" values in the final result reducedVal.pop_list = reducedVal.pop_list.concat(countObjVals[idx].pop); but see in my question above why it didn't work although it should have according to http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/pivot/

Comment: Asya, can I submit this as a bug to 10 gen ?

Comment: I doubt there is a bug here.  I think there is some information that is not being communicated clearly here...  Just not sure what it is :)

Comment: Okay, I think I know what it is.  I think you have a single top level document which has "actor1383" twice in its actors array.  It would explain the counts - and since you are using projection when displaying list of popularities we don't see if that's the case.

Comment: Ok, what about any pointers on how to debug the result. I tried by actually trying to record every pop from every movie, but it doesn't seem to work properly.

Comment: I think that must be it. I will verify by visually inspecting all 41 documents.

Comment: Thank you. Verified.
`code`for (var idx = 0; idx < this.actors.length; idx++) {
                           var key = this.title;
         var value = 1; 
         if(this.actors[idx].id == 1383){
        
        emit(key, value);
         }
                           
                       }
`code`{ "_id" : "NKTKEKfbxFrudVi", "value" : { "count" : 2 } }
I'll ask the debugging question separately.